# OAuth error 403 (forbidden) on Youtube Api v3 with python

Tags: python, youtube

I'm trying to use the Youtube API v3 with python from my local machine but I keep ending up in 403 forbidden/error after the authorisation screen.

I'm running this Python example code:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list?apix=true

When running it from there, it works fine. When copy the code to a .py file and running it locally I first get an error:

> AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'

But I can fix that by changing:

```
credentials = flow.run_console()
```

into:

```
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
```

Then it opens my browser with a permission screen (wrong browser, so I copy it to the one with the same google account logged-in) and I then click on allow. Click the channel name and then I get 403 forbidden....

I tried most of the things I found online:

- check if API is enabled
- sets scopes
- restrict api-key (although I use oauth)
- Create new project / credentials

I also checked this: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#python

I actually got the same problem with a wrapper library (that wraps the YouTube API in a more friendly easy to use interface) that I tried before. Hence, me trying to use the API directly.

What am I Missing here?

Comment: The problem seems to be specific to accessing brand accounts (yt channels). When selecting the google account it works fine, but when selecting the brand account I get 403. Brand account was created by the same google account.

Comment: Found I workaround by setting the app to external and then 'test' and added my own google account as a test user.... Still unsure about the right way to manage a youtube channel (brand account) via the yt v3 api.